# Are there any other ways to link to a page other than the <a> tag?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for other ways to create a link to another page without using the a tag. I was wondering if javascript's  pushstate() and popstate() methods would work?

Comment: Depending on the motivation, there might be different solutions. Can you add to your question why you want to achieve that?

Comment: @ThomasW because I created a web page which have different tabs. Now for me to transition into those tabs, I created separate pages. I suggested to use `<a>` tags, but my client said it would be better for me to use the `pushstate()` and `popstate()` methods since it all just happens in the same page. How can I do that?

Comment: But that's not really related to the `<a>` element, is it? You want to trigger some JavaScript event, and that event can be attached to any element, including an `<a>` element. I would still use an `<a>` element. It's more semantic and I presume it has accessibility advantages (though I'm no a11y expert).

Comment: point noted. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create absolutely any tag and hang a click event on it, and in the handler function make a redirect to the page you need.

Html:

```
<div id="link">Link</div>
```

Js:

```
let el = document.getElementById("link");
el.onclick = () => { window.location.href = "/other_page" };
```

Answer (score 2):

you can with javascript/jquery. like that;

```
$(this).on('click',selector,function(){
location.href(url);
})
```